# Barcodes not printing with Dymo SDK & c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, dymo

I have a simple label with 2 barcodes on it.  I'm able to open the label, and print the label, however the barcodes are not printing.  The text labels are.

```
_label = Framework.Open("c:\\temp\\inventory.label");
_label.SetObjectText("part_num", txtPartNumber.Text);
_label.SetObjectText("serial_num", txtSerialNum.Text);
_label.Print("DYMO LabelWriter 450");
```

Comment: This is really not enough information for anyone to give proper advice.
However;
did you set the label fields to a barcode font?
is this the same font as used by the dymo driver?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Dymo label framework.  I created a test label with 2 barcodes on it called "part_num" and "serial_num", and 2 text fields and saved the label.  When the code tells the label to print, the only thing that comes out is the 2 text fields.  I'm using barcode font 128.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Had to use the SDK and not the label framework.

```
var myDymoAddin = new DymoAddIn();
var myLabel = new DymoLabels();
if (myDymoAddin.Open(@"c:\temp\inventory.label"))
{
   myLabel.SetField("part_num", txtPartNumber.Text);
   myLabel.SetField("serial_num", txtSerialNum.Text);
   myDymoAddin.StartPrintJob();
   myDymoAddin.Print(1, false);
   myDymoAddin.EndPrintJob();
 }
```